# Return different rows between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to check and return all rows that are not common between two tables?

Table 1:

```
pk    name    date
102   John    1/1/16
101   Bob     1/1/17
```

Table 2:

```
pk    name    date
102   John    1/1/16
104   Bob     1/1/17
105   Ted     1/1/18
```

Ideally, I can also limit the query by date. So If I limit by Date < 1/1/18, the result would be:

```
table pk    name    date
1     101   Bob     1/1/17
2     104   Bob     1/1/17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table1
union 
select * from table2
except
(select * from table1 intersect select * from table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 t1
where not exsits (
     select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.pk = t1.pk
) and t1.Date < '2018/1/1'

union all

select * from table2 t2
where not exsits (
     select 1 from table1 t1 where t2.pk = t1.pk
)  and t2.Date < '2018/1/1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXCEPT` for this like

```
select pk,
    name,
    date from table1
except
select pk,
    name,
    date from table2;
```

(OR) using `NOT IN` operator along with `UNION` like

```
select * from table1 where pk not in (select distinct pk from table2);
union
select * from table2 where pk not in (select distinct pk from table1);
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise with your sample data:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(( SELECT 1 as [table],* FROM
        (SELECT * FROM #TABLE_1
         EXCEPT
         SELECT * FROM #TABLE_2) AS Inner1)
UNION
(SELECT 2 as [table],* FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM #TABLE_2
         EXCEPT
         SELECT * FROM #TABLE_1) AS Inner2)) AS Final
WHERE Final.date < '2018-01-01'
```